# How to export image as a plane to .dae/collada file, while maintaining transparencies (Blender version 2.79,2.8,2.9) for STK/AGI software?

Tags: export, transparency, collada, dae

I am trying to make a rocket exhaust .dae/collada object for a trajectory software called AGI/STK. A muzzle flash would be the same thing. I can import a .png file with transparencies into blender without any issues. However, when I export a collada file I repeatedly get the same result of the transparency showing along with the picture.

I have tried Blender 2.7, 2.8, and 2.9. I have attempted to use Blender Game, Cycles, and Evee. I have tried to export directly, and I have tried to bake the texture. I always end up with the same result. Any help that will aid me in making the transparent portion of the .png file invisible, would be much oblidged.

[image: PNG as seen in Blender]

[image: Screen capture of exported .dae/collada image in AGI/STK]gur.com/zPApw.pngf

Comment: Recall something similar re export to three.js Try setting the alpha to not exactly zero, eg 0.001

Comment: Is your problem with rendering in Blender, or with rendering elsewhere?  Your Blender render looks okay.  You need to be looking at material specifications for the renderer you're using.  Materials are *not* necessarily cross-engine compatible, although some exporters try their best to make them so.

Comment: batFinger... Is this the the alpha setting in "Materials" or in "Textures" that you are referring to?

Comment: Nathan...I actually was successful once with getting the result in blender (2.7), but I accidently deleted the file at a later time. I cannot retrace my steps. So, the renderer will show transparencies if the collada export is done correctly.  This should be a stupid simple retrace of previous work, but Blender is so damn finicky, I cannot get the .da/collada file to export rcorrectly.